# Pandas custom functions in returning column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Please help me out in writing pandas custom functions, in 
the confusion loop in returning specific row and col values as custom results,i want to return col means without using slicing no user defined functions like numpy(np.mean) and i need only parameter to pass is dataset 'df' to custom function.
In layman way i want to return column ['A','B'] means from function col_mean() by passing dataset "df" without using pandas slicing and predefined functions like mean/np.mean
Below is my dataset please give me code logic in getting col means.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [10,20,30], 'B': [20, 30, 10]})
 def col_men(df):
     means=[0 for i in range(df.shape[1])]
     for k in range(df.shape[1]):
         col_values=[row[k] for row in df]
         means[k]=sum(col_values)/float(len(df))
     return means
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `range(df.shape[1])` use `enumerate(df.columns)`, so you keep both name and position:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [10,20,30], 'B': [20, 30, 10]})
def col_men(df):
    means=[0 for i in range(df.shape[1])]
    for index, k in enumerate(df.columns):
        col_values=[row for row in df[k]]
        means[index]=sum(col_values)/len(df)
    return means
col_men(df)
```